# Where does the cookie mo_page_views_counter come from?

Tags: plugins, cookies

```
mo_page_views_counter: 3
mo_has_visited: true
mo_is_new: true
```

I have the following cookies set on my wordpress site... However I do not set these cookies and I have turned off all plugins that might be setting cookies.

Should I be worried?

Comment: This is set by either a plugin or a poorly coded theme. Disable all plugins and switch to a default theme (Twenty-X). Also check the mu-plugins.

Comment: The plugin 'mailoptin' sets those cookies via it's mailoptin.js file, perhaps you still had that js script cached in the html after disabling plugins?